Statamic url's not combining
I am upgrading statamic from version 3.3 to 4.5 and having issues with URL's not combining for child entries. For the setup of this package, we are also using the statamic eloquent driver to use the database for this, rather than files.
A parent entry previously had a slug of "home", with the child issue having the slug of "test". The database column "uri" for that specific entry has the uri as "/home/test", however the url is not accessible. Only changing this to be a flat structure, such as "/test" works.
Additionally, when using the dashboard to manually update a child issue, the uri will also update to this flat version automatically.
Is there any way to change config / alter child entries so that these can retain their full path?

Are your collections orderable and did you define route rules for the collection as per the documentation?

All of these pages are in the same collection which start at /. Previously, nested entries here worked fine when they targeted the parent, but this is no longer the case. This functionality worked before the upgrade, unless something changed in the meantime.

After looking back, at some point the config had changed from in the process of the upgrade script. Reverting this old script (and adding the route as "routes": "/{parent_uri}/{slug}" did the trick. Make an answer and I shall accept

According to the documentation, you are able to create Route rules for specific collections.
These route rules can utilize some meta-variables, one of which is parent_uri which is only available in case the collection is orderable.
Configuring these route rules will fix your problem.
